# Image in header opaque

Tags: css, html, opacity

still busy to learn HTML5 and CSS for my school project. But got a question and i'm stumped.

The image and links i have in my nav bar, the face with text, gets transparent. Even though it's not in the same div, nor class as the header itself, which has an opacity value.

the post is, the image AND links should be completely visible, and on TOP of that background opacity.

In advance, sorry for the probably shoddy coding and naming of classes.

Here's the links:
[actual site](http://pastebin.com/sCngV9re)
[html/css](http://dws.cmi.hanze.nl/228677/home.html)

Comment: Please do not post links to your site and/or files. Instead, place the related code itself in your post and if you can, make a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that replicates the issue you are having.

Comment: why you  giving opacity in  class `header`?

Answer (score 1):

your header div has opacity set to 0.7 so that results in everything inside it being semi transparent.

if you want only your header **background** to be transparent, you can either add the transparency directly to your header background-image. or you could use an rgba background color, if your header background should be a semi transparent specific color. (http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

if all of that doesn't suit your needs, you could always get fancy with something like shown in here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the essential problem is that you have one `div` nested inside another.

Although your `.flub` class has its opacity set to 1.0, the only `div` it applies to is inside a `.header` `div`, with an opacity of 0.7. So your `.flub` `div` is displaying with 100% of the available capacity, which is only 70% due to it being nested within your `.header` `div` (which is set to 70% opacity). Consider setting the opacity of the other elements separately, rather than setting the opacity of the entire `.header` `div`.